# Name server registration

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

My scenario is I bought my domain from a crappy domain registration service company. they only allow me to change dns servers for the selected domain. however i dont wanna use a free service such as zoneedit.com or opendns.com . what i want is forexample my domain is test.com and i want to create ns1.test.com and ns2.test.com, i have a dedicated server with full permission. i set up a dns server would it be possible just adding these records to this dns server and do I need to register these ns1 and ns2 somewhere?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to point the domain's NS record at your server, and on the server, create any records you want (including an A record for ns1.yourdomain.com/ns2.yourdomain.com)

Comment: do i not need to register my dns server somewhere?

Comment: Just telling the registrar your nameserver's IP will do

Comment: works! http://fj.com.tr/ thanks for helping

Comment: Just to reiterate...  you really really really don't want to just point both NS records to the same location.  I know you're going to do it anyway, but you really shouldn't.

Comment: @MichaelGraff i know what you mean, this was just educational purposes. For better availibity the more name servers pointing to different servers is the best. I've waited 12 years to say this :D

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add glue records to the parent.

This is because ns1.test.com and ns2.test.com live inside test.com.

If they were outside it, then nothing special would have to happen.

Chances are your registrar (the place where you registered your domain) will have a way to 'add a name server.'  This will ask for the name, and the IP address of the server.  Enter the two you have (they should be on different machines).  Then you can add NS records to point to your DNS servers.

Note that you really do need two (or more) name servers.  This is to protect in case one server is down or unreachable.

Comment: you mean different machine than my dedicated server?

Comment: DNS wants (but does not STRICTLY require) two machines to serve your zone.  One is called a 'primary' or 'master' and the others are 'secondary' or 'slaves'.  However, they must all be up and operational at all times.  This is for reliability.  You can run your primary on your box, and find a low-cost secondary service somewhere to serve as the other DNS server.

Comment: would it technically work if i point these 2 name servers to my own box? even though i know its not good practice.

Comment: which i will create 2 A records for ns1.test.com -> IP1 ns2.test.com -> IP1

Comment: That is what is called 'broken' in the DNS world.  You're avoiding the requirements many place on DNS by faking it out.  What it means is you will no service whatsoever should your single server go down.  This means mail will bounce, web site users will get a 'cannot find this hostname' error, and overall you will be flaky.  If you want this, go for it, but it's not what you should do.

Comment: so how it should be, to buy a new dedicated server and setup another dns server on it?

Comment: That is one option, but not the one I'd choose.  I'd find a cheap DNS secondary option.  Somewhere there has to be one that will serve as a secondary, and probably do it better than you can with your own set of servers.  For instance, http://www.dyndns.com/services/dns/secdns/ seems to cost $29.95/year to do your secondary service.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register ns1 and ns2 to specific IPs. Your web host, if they permit private nameservers, should give you the IPs to use. You need to go to the "host summary" section (or similar section) within your domain manager, add the host name (NS1.test.com), and the IP its associated with. Do the same with NS2.